# average gridded climate data for duplicated times in r

Tags: r, spatial, weather

I have a gridded climate dataset, such as:

```
# generate time vector
time1 <- seq(14847.5,14974.5, by = 1)
time2 <- seq(14947.5,14974.5, by = 1)
time <- c(time1,time2)
time <- as.POSIXct(time*86400,origin='1970-01-01 00:00')

# generate lat and lon coordinates
lat <- seq(80,90, by = 1)
lon <- seq(20,30, by = 1)

# generate 3dimensional array
dat <- array(runif(length(lat)*length(lon)*length(time)),
             dim = c(length(lon),length(lat),length(time)))
```

such that

```
> dim(dat)
[1]  11  11 156
```

the dimensions of the data are describing the variable at different longitude (`dim = 1`), latitude (`dim = 2`), and time (`dim = 3`).

The issue I have at the moment is that some of the times are repeated, something to do with overlapping sensors measuring the data. Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible to only keep the unique times for `dat`, but average the data within the grid for the duplicated times i.e. if there are two repeated days we take the average value in each latitude and longitude grid for that time.

I can find the unique times as:

```
# only select unique times
new_time <- unique(time)
unique_time <- unique(time)
```

The following code then aims to loop through each grid (`lat`/`lon`) and average all of the duplicated days.

```
# loop through lat/lon coordinates to generate new data
new_dat <- array(dim = c(length(lon),length(lat),length(new_time)))
for(i in 1:length(lon)){
  for(ii in 1:length(lat)){
    dat2 <- dat[i,ii,]
    dat2b <- NA
    for(k in 1:length(unique_time)){
      idx <- time == unique_time[k]
      dat2b[k] <- mean(dat2[idx], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    new_dat[i,ii,] <- dat2b
  }
}
```

I'm convinced that this provides the correct answer, but I'm certain there is a much cleaner method do achieve this.

I should also note that my data is quite large (i.e. `k = 7000`), so this last loop is not very efficient, to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*My original answer:*

This is a bit more concise and efficient by use of `aggregate`:

```
for(i in 1:length(lon)){
  for(ii in 1:length(lat)){
    new_dat[i,ii,] <- as.numeric(aggregate(dat[i,ii,], by=list(time),mean)$x)
  }
}
```

It still has 2 out of the 3 of the loops, but it manages to bypass creating `dat2`, `dat2b`, and `unique_time`.

*My improved answer:*

```
f <- function(i, ii){as.numeric(aggregate(dat[i,ii,], by=list(time),mean)$x)}

for(i in 1:nrow(expand.grid(1:length(lon),1:length(lat)))){
  new_dat[expand.grid(1:length(lon),1:length(lat))[i,1],
          expand.grid(1:length(lon),1:length(lat))[i,2],] <- 
    f(expand.grid(1:length(lon),1:length(lat))[i,1],expand.grid(1:length(lon),
           1:length(lat))[i,2])
}
```

Got it down to just 1 loop. We could probably bypass that loop too with an `apply`.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. To be even better, is there a way of modifying it so that aggregate command can be used on the third dimension i.e. without having to loop through all of the different lat/lon combinations? Your updated answer kind of does this but I was thinking that there must be another solution. For example, one can use abind to merge the third dimensions of an array, thus I was thinking that something similar must be possible. At the moment it still takes a while to run through my data - I'm trying to find the most optimum method for this problem.

Comment: @EmmaTebbs Glad it works! Let me see if I can get that last improvement you mentioned in your comment. I'll come back to this during lunch today (approx. 6 hours from now) and see what I can do.